# What does this expression do in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I saw this code on the internet: http://jsfiddle.net/q9dEB/392/

```
$(function()
{
    $('#txtDate').datepicker({ beforeShowDay:
      function(dt)
      {

        return [dt.getDay() != 0  && dt.getDay() != 6 , ""];
      }
   });
});
```

My question is about this part:

```
return [dt.getDay() != 0  && dt.getDay() != 6 , ""];
```

Is it like a lambda of a list of comprehension function? I don't understand how  it works.

Answer (score 4):

No, it just returns an array. The first item in the array is the result of evaluating the expression `dt.getDay() != 0  && dt.getDay() != 6` which (since it's an expression using the `&&` operator) will either be `true` or `false`. The second item in the array is an empty string (`""`).

So the end result returned will look something like `[true, ""]`.

Longhand, you could write it like this:

```
var returnVal = [];
var day = dt.getDay();
var result = false;
if (day != 0 && day != 6) result = true;
returnVal.push(result);
returnVal.push("");
return returnVal;
```

I hope that breakdown helps you to see what each bit of the code in that line is doing.